# Cropping a specific part of an image in R

Tags: image, crop

I want to crop images in R. I use this code for my data, but I get error. It does not make sense because there is no img.crop: I found that the class of image is "cimg". Do you think I need to change it to array class? Do you know how?

```
## example where you know where to crop the image

img <- load.image('C:/image/17.jpg')
plot(img)
dim(img)
print(k)
img22 <- crop.image(img ,xleft=446,ybottom=7,xright=203,ytop=256)
split.screen(c(1,2))
screen(1)
image2(img,asp=1,main='Original')
screen(2)
image2(img22[[1]],asp=1,main='Cropped')
class(img)
```

Error in crop.image(img, xleft = 446, ybottom = 7, xright = 203, ytop = 256) :
object 'img.crop' not found

Comment: The `c` function is commonly used to combine values into a vector or list in R. `split.screen(c(1,2))` makes screen 1 and screen 2. You can Google search "split.screen r" and "crop.image r" to learn more about these functions and how they're used. Usually the first link in these searches about R functions is the vignette or a useful documentation or tutorial about them. (That's how I found out about `split.screen`.)

Comment: Regarding the help that you seek, you should show us your attempt, the error/problem that you face, and provide a question specifically addressing that problem (if the problem has not already been solved on Stack Overflow or elsewhere--do some research). [Here are some tips on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you're just asking how to crop an image, it seems like many R functions do it. (Again, I easily found them in a Google search.) See if this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46439293/6288065