# how to crop left side of image in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, crop, ggsave

I used superheat to make a plot and I want to remove the waste on the left. I tried to save with ggsave and play with the width/height but it is centered so I lose the borders and cant choose to crop just the left side.

Is it doable?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crop image in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46439293/crop-image-in-r)

Comment: no it does not work

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it does work (read [magick vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html#Image_IO) for more info). The framework / package is a beast:

```r
library(magick)

image_read("nn2C6.png") |>
  image_crop(geometry = geometry_area(width = 657, height = 0, x_off = 45, y_off = 0)) |>
  image_write(path = "nn2C6_cropped.png", format = "png")
```

Use `image_trim()` instead of `image_crop()` if you also want to remove the upper border.